# Why is this change of log base as such?

Tags: logarithms

I found the following in a textbook:

[image]

I can't understand how this happend. Isn't the denominator suppose to be $log_{e}2$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be $\log_e 2$.

Comment: oh wow so this book is wrong??
https://books.google.com/books?id=RWBwCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT372&lpg=PT372&dq=log2k+upper+bound+entropy&source=bl&ots=aA9igapd6j&sig=EOwWpQJ5PlaJHbj6rXqJl0AN4Sk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsueDb0tLdAhXjT98KHbN7C7IQ6AEwA3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=log2k%20upper%20bound%20entropy&f=false

Comment: I would say so. It looks like it's just a minor typo.

Comment: Typos happen...

Answer (score 0):

This is a typo in the book. The general rule for the conversion of logarithms with different bases $a$ and $b$ is
$$
\log_a(x) = \dfrac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(a)} \;.
$$